# How to debug python flask application into VS Code 2017

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am working on the flask project. I am executing my project using

```
py app.py -v
```

The `app.py` is the main file that runs the program. I have a `backend.py` where I call routes and methods.
This is vs code settings

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "app.py"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload",
                "-v"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I am also getting error due to passing `-v` as argument. Is that any specific way to pass the argument?

I want to debug `backend.py` method or route when user submit or perform any operation but my main application start by `app.py`. Please guide me, how I could do with vs code 2017.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `-v` to `flask run`, not to your own script. I suspect Flask has a way to flag when arguments to `flask run` stops and arguments to your own code starts (typically `--` in other programs).

Comment: Would you suggest how I should have to pass argument -v to my script app.py ??

Comment: @hardika you will have to read the Flask docs since I unfortunately don't know that myself.